# probably event bubbled on wrong element in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to flip a simple element on page on mouse click. It works but not on every click. I must click several times in different places across the tile and then the tile flip. 
Code is executed as I see in the console, but it looks like click on wrong elements is fired.

I have custom directive with link method:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.hideClicked = true;
            scope.showClicked = false;

            scope.backClicked = function () {
                console.log('show front')
                scope.hideClicked = false;
                scope.showClicked = true;
            }

            scope.frontClicked = function () {
                console.log('hide front');
                scope.hideClicked = true;
                scope.showClicked = false;
            }
        console.log(scope, element, attrs);
    }
```

and in the template

```
<div class="tile" ng-class="{'hide-elem': hideClicked,'show-elem': showClicked }"> 
    <span class="front" ng-click="frontClicked()">{{itemData.value}}</span> 
    <span class="back" ng-click="backClicked();"></span> 
</div>
```

Full code to reproduct is here: https://codepen.io/lkurylo/pen/Laprjx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both child-`span`-Elements use absolute positioning, so it seems as if the browser decides that the second element is displayed "on top" of the first. As a result, the click only registers on the `back`-Element, which happens to be the top-element.

I suggest you display only one element at any given time, e.g. by adding `ng-show` or `ng-if` to both elements.

```
<span class="front" ng-if="showClicked" ng-click="..."></span>
<span class="back" ng-if="hideClicked" ng-click="..."></span>
```

Comment: That was the case. To preserve animation, elements must be show/hide after delay. Corrected version: https://codepen.io/lkurylo/pen/JzGLKy